# How to confirm that object owners can grant and revoke privileges on objects he owns?

Tags: oracle, permissions

I'm trying to bring my systems in compliance with a certain set of standards. One of them in confirming that the Oracle default behavior of allowing users to grant and revoke privileges to objects they own is still active. I have no idea how this would even be disabled in the first place, but I'm trying to figure out what evidence I can provide that it is still active other than "this is default behavior of Oracle." Is there a way to confirm this in views like dba_tab_privs or something?

Any assistance would be appreciated. Let me know if you need me to clarify.

Comment: Your company wants you to test the default functionality of the Oracle database? That would be a challenge from me. Sounds like a waste of T&M.

Comment: It isn't just "the default behavior", it's the **only** behavior.  Owners always have full control on their own objects (including grants and revokes on those objects).  That's why separation of container schemas from accounts that login to the database is so key to database security.

Comment: This was basically my understanding as well. A waste of time and a silly check for behavior that can't possibly be changed. Thank you both. To the powers that be, this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't just "the default behavior", it's the only behavior. Owners always have full control on their own objects (including grants and revokes on those objects). That's why separation of container schemas from accounts that login to the database is so key to database security.

> **Disclaimer**
>   The original answer was posted as a comment by [@KrisJohnston](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/68832/kris-johnston)

#### Addition

There is a slight twist to the answer in that the permissions can be changed so that the owner can longer modify his own objects, **BUT** the owner is then no longer the owner. This is a loss of ownership for the original owner.

This can be achieved using the following technique:

[How to change an Oracle table owner](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_change_table_schema_owner.htm)

> create table bill.emp as select * from scott.emp;